# .NET Regex: negate previous character for the first character in string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Consider following string

```
"Some" string with "quotes" and \"pre-slashed\" quotes
```

Using regex, I want to find all the double quotes with no slash before them. So I want the regex to find four matches for the example sentence
This....

```
[^\\]"
```

...would find only three of them. I suppose that's because of the regex's state machine which is first validating the command to negate the presence of the slash.

That means I need to write a regex with some kind of look-behind, but I don't know how to work with these lookaheads and lookbehinds...im not even sure that's what I'm looking for.

The following attempt returns 6, not 4 matches...

```
"(?<!\\)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"(?<!\\")
```

Is what you're looking for

If you want to match "Some" and "quotes", then

```
(?<!\\")(?!\\")"[a-zA-Z0-9]*"
```

will do

Explanation:

- `(?<!\\")` - Negative lookbehind. Specifies a group that can not match before your main expression
- `(?!\\")` - Negative lookahead. Specifies a group that can not match after your main expression
- `"[a-zA-Z0-9]*"` - String to match between regular quotes

Which means - match anything that doesn't come with \" before and \" after, *but* is contained inside double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, move the quote after the lookbehind, like:

```
(?<!\\)"
```

Also be ware of cases like

```
"escaped" backslash \\"string\"
```

You can use an expression like this to handle those:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
(?<!\\)(?<qs>"[^"]+")
```

**Explanation**

```
<!--
(?<!\\)(?<qs>"[^"]+")

Options: case insensitive

Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind) «(?<!\\)»
   Match the character “\” literally «\\»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “qs” «(?<qs>"[^"]+")»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
   Match any character that is NOT a “"” «[^"]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match the character “"” literally «"»
-->
```

**code**

```
try {
    if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"(?<!\\)(?<qs>""[^""]+"")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
        // Successful match
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```